# Why does my input box not accept data on my website

Tags: html

I have a form to enable people to provide an email address but it wont allow any input. The site is [www.pbadvisory.com.au](http://www.pbadvisory.com.au)  and here is my HTML code:

```
<form action="mailto:jdoe@pbadvisory.com.au" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="newsletter_email" />
    <input type="submit" id="newsletter_subscribe" value="Subscribe" name="submit" />
</form>
```

any suggestions to fix would be appreciated

Comment: what do you mean input anyway?

Comment: umm do you know how internet works right

Answer (score 1):

Just went through your site. Actually it is allowing to input the text. But the text color is white and background is white, so its invisible. Change the text color so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `mailto:` as a form action.  If you want a form that sends e-mail, it must be done server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following Changes!

```
<form action="MAILTO:jdoe@pbadvisory.com.au" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="newsletter_email" />
    <input type="submit" id="newsletter_subscribe" value="Subscribe" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form method should be '**post**' not get. That's the reason for your problem. Any way here is the full code with email subject is also included.

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:youremail@youremail.com?Subject=Email Subject" enctype="text/plain">
E-mail:<input id="emailAddress" name="E-mail" type="text" maxlength="24" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Send Email" /> 
</form>
```

Hope it helped.

**Update:**
Just a note this is not the right way if you want users to get subscribe with your web site.